# How to create an asp.net calendar link to database?

Tags: asp.net, database, ajax, vb.net, calendar

We are trying to implement a calendar in an asp.net page and link it a database. The calendar should highlights dates based on data in the database tables similar to airline ticket booking calendar.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No one is going to write an application for you here...  If you have a specific question you should ask it.  Without that here is my best advice.

Start by looking at how to implement asp.net's calendar control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Then look at using ADO.NET to communicate from your web app to your db.  Here is a good place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A calendar has a property SelectedDates which is a list of the dates that have been selected. All you need to do if you get a list of dates from a database is add them to the property SelectedDates.

For example:

```
Public Sub Calendar_Prerender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calendar.PreRender
    Dim tomorrow As DateTime = Now.AddDays(1)
    Dim nextday As DateTime = Now.AddDays(2)

    Calendar.SelectedDates.Add(tomorrow)
    Calendar.SelectedDates.Add(nextday)
End Sub
```

The calendar loads with tomorrow and the day after selected.